# Is there a reason for using firebase .once without using the parameter in the callback?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading the code of a node project which does something like:

```
var firebase = new Firebase(...);
var ref = firebase.child('path');

// more code
// then there's a function that gets called as a result of a POST request

function doSomething() {
  ref.once('value', function() { // notice how the callback doesn't get any parameter
    // do something
  });
}
```

My understanding of firebase is fairly basic but I don't quite understand why would someone ask for a firebase snapshot of a particular path without caring about the result at all.

Is there a reason for doing this that I cannot think of (crazy event loop tricks, maybe)?

Comment: Nobody can really say that but the author of said code. But they could be getting the snapshot through the implicit `arguments` parameter of JavaScript.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen well, your comment may be worth an answer. I'm not looking for a definitive answer but a list of possible reason and/or things I need to check in order to asses whether I can reasonably get rid of that call or not.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've seen you are a Firebase engineer, it would be very helpful to me if you could confirm whether or not this practice has a possible use-case in the Firebase world. As I said, I'm just starting on Firebase and I'm not entirely sure if the .once method has other side effects not entirely specified in the documentation. Excluding all other reasons tied to the specific project, is it an intended use-case, in Firebase world, using .once this way? [`arguments` is not used in the callback]. Thank you very much.

Comment: Questions like "is there any way this could be useful" are not simple to answer. There may be, but I'd never use Firebase in code like that without a comment as to what my reasoning is.

Answer (score -2):

Use "**fcm-node**", it will work perfectly.

Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node.